# Real Time temperature plotting with python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am currently making a project which requires real time monitoring of various quantities like temperature, pressure, humidity etc. I am following a approach of making individual arrays of all the sensors and ploting a graph using matplotlib and drwnow.

```
HOST = "localhost"
PORT = 4223

UID1 = "tsJ" # S1

from tinkerforge.ip_connection import IPConnection
from tinkerforge.bricklet_ptc import BrickletPTC
import numpy as np
import serial

import matplotlib
from matplotlib.ticker import ScalarFormatter, FormatStrFormatter

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import style
style.use('ggplot')

from drawnow import *

# creating arrays to feed the data

tempC1 = []

def makeafig():

    # creating subplots
    fig1 = plt.figure(1)

    a = fig1.add_subplot(111)

    #setting up axis label, auto formating of axis and title
    a.set_xlabel('Time [s]', fontsize = 10)
    a.set_ylabel('Temperature [°C]', fontsize = 10)
    y_formatter = matplotlib.ticker.ScalarFormatter(useOffset=False)
    a.yaxis.set_major_formatter(y_formatter)
    title1 = "Current Room Temperature (Side1): " + str(temperature1/100) + " °C"
    a.set_title(title1, fontsize = 10)

    #plotting the graph
    a.plot(tempC1, "#00A3E0")

    #saving the figure
    fig1.savefig('RoomTemperature.png', dpi=100)

while True:

    ipcon = IPConnection() # Create IP connection
    ptc1 = BrickletPTC(UID1, ipcon) # S1 

    ipcon.connect(HOST, PORT) # Connect to brickd

    #setting the temperature from PTC bricklet

    temperature1 = ptc1.get_temperature()


    #processing data from a temperature sensor to 1st array
    dataArray1=str(temperature1/100).split(',')
    temp1 = float(dataArray1[0])
    tempC1.append(temp1)

    #making a live figure
    drawnow(makeafig)
    plt.draw()
```

This is the approach I found good on the internet and it is working. The only problem I am facing is It consumes more time if I made more arrays for other sensors and the plot being made lags from the real time when I compare it with a stopwatch.

Is there any good and efficient approach for obtaining live graphs that will be efficient with lot of sensors and doen't lag with real time.
Or any command to clear up the already plotted array values?

I'd be obliged if anyone can help me with this problem.

Comment: Are you showing them on a website? If yes, what about generating the json (your plot data) with python and generating an interactive chart with javascript?

Comment: @PhilipB Thank you for replying. No I am not directly showing it on website. The saved graph keeps on updating till the script runs and then I have an another completely different script that sends this saved figure to to a cloud server.

Comment: Have you considered using threads to obtain the data? Also, maybe there is too much data to send at once with the other script?

Comment: @mpurg thank you for your efforts. I should try using threads to collect data and plot the graph. That other script is completely different it just sends the saved image to the cloud server through LAN. Do you think using threads rather than arrays is a good option? I am sorry for this silly question, I am a newby.

Comment: I don't get it.. If you only need the result at the end (when you upload it to the server), why don't you plot the figure once at the end?

Comment: Also; what ends your `while` loop? I really wonder where you found that code on the internet; I would call that a pretty bad example.......

Comment: @Bart it is actually a live monitoring on the cloud server in my university. one script(the one I mentioned here) plots the graphs and keeps on saving the figure till the script runs while on the other hand the other script keeps updating continuosly that saved figure on the cloud server.

Comment: @Bart I found this on a youtube channel of Paul McWhorter. He used Arduino and python to generate plots. I am very new to the programming so I got stuck with it because it was working. Now as I am learning the language I too think its a bad example

Comment: Anyhow... With your current example it is difficult to guess what makes it slow once you try to plot more sensors. How do you plot them (more `subplots`?), how many data points per plot are we talking about (`1`,`10`,`100000000`?). I don't think we can really help you unless you create a simple minimal example which reproduces the problem. Can you reproduce it if you substitute the `get_temperature()` with a random number?

Comment: @Bart yes I am plotting with more subplots, say 4 on one figure. The number of data points depends till the device is switched off or the script is closed (that I haven't thought about it) but yeah for the time perspective I'd say a minimum of 1800 seconds that means 1800 data points on a graph or more.  I'd like to ask that, does filling data in arrays continuosly makes the process slow or is it my misconception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'd like to ask that, does filling data in arrays continuosly makes the process slow or is it my misconception?

That one is easy to test; creating an empty list and appending a few thousand values to it takes roughly 10^-4 seconds, so that shouldn't be a problem. For me somewhat surprisingly, it is actually faster than creating and filling a fixed size `numpy.ndarray` (but that is probably going to depend on the size of the list/array).

I quickly played around with your `makeafig()` function, placing `a = fig1.add_subplot(111)` up to (including) `a.plot(..)` in a simple `for i in range(1,5)` loop, with `a = fig1.add_subplot(2,2,i)`; that makes `makeafig()` about 50% slower, but differences are only about 0.1-0.2 seconds. Is that in line with the lag that you are experiencing?

That's about what I can test without the real data, my next step would be to time the part from `ipcon=..` to `temperature1=..`. Perhaps the bottleneck is simply the retrieval of the data? I'm sure that there are several examples on SO on how to time parts of Python scripts, for these kind of problems something like the example below should be sufficient:

```
import time
t0 = time.time()
# do something
dt = time.time() - t0
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and help. The kind of lag I am experiencing is 7 seconds on my graph to 1 on real time. Anyway I#ll try to learn this time function you mentioned and implement in my script. Thanks again for your valuable feedback.